# Compile a typescript node js app including dependencies

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, body-parser, tsc

I have created a Node.js app using typescript and trying to compile it. Currently, the build only contains the source files in the `src` folder. But I also want to include the dependencies like `express`, `body-parser`, etc from `node_modules` in the final build. This is similar to how `webpack` compiles all the files together creating bundles.

How can I do this using the typescript compiler only? Or it can be done using webpack only?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript compiler only compiles typescript to javascript. You have to manage yourself the build as you want.

I would use a post script to organize your program. Here is a example of pre and post script using `npm run build` [Pre and post script gist](https://gist.github.com/coryhouse/b7ff5e6d1e41b762c35b)

Comment: So it means that I'll have to use webpack only for the type of build I want. Can't it be done by changing some options in the `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Here you can see all the options in the `tsconfig.json` file if you want to check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html